# Pagination - creating a new document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, pagination, redux-thunk

I wanted to know how this is usually done client side since I didn't find a good solution. I'm using pagination on questions/answers threads similar to Stack Overflow where you can upvote/downvote comments so the data comes like this:

```
data: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
limit: 10
skip: 0
total: 12
```

and the user adds a new comment, how should this be handled?

```
const addCommentToPost = (comment, postId) => {
  return dispatch => {
    addComment({
        comment, postId
      })
      .then(result => {
        // ??
      });
  };
};
```

Should all the data be re-fetched? Should I somehow append the comment to the data I already have and increase the total?

Answer (score 3):

Normally what I would do is when user adds a comment, it'd be sent to the api to be saved to the database and then on success the api would return the saved comment (including its id) and you'd add that comment client side to react/redux state without refetching all the data from the api.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me clarify where I'm struggling with this - keeping the pagination correct when adding to it

Answer (score 0):

call your api here first, if success then store it to state

```
const addCommentToPost = (comment, postId) => {
      return dispatch => {
        addComment({
            comment, postId
            //call your api here first, if success then store it to state
          })
          .then(result => {
            // ??
          });
      };
    };
```